# Who first wrote the kernel for Mac OS X based operating systems?

Tags: mac

Was it Steve Jobs? I mean not the idea, but who actually made it happen through the physical work itself?

Was it a single individual who wrote the bootstrapping software, kernel, graphics, all other assets, etc.?

I am curious on the coder, not the incentive or ideal, even though I do care on both.

I am also curious on the first ever kernel or boot loading software, not current coders, but the initial and original one(s) of that time who did this.

Comment: My initial reaction to this question was to propose to close it, but on second thought it might be interesting to see where it leads us to. The OS X kernel doesn't have a single "father" though so you might try to rephrase the question a bit more broadly. And maybe read the Wikipedia article on OS X to see whether this already answers your question.

Answer (score 5):

It wasn't really Steve Jobs. Steve Jobs helped create OSX which is derived from the original operating system kernal.

OSX is *based on* the [Mach Kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_kernel). "Mach is an operating system kernel developed at Carnegie Mellon University to support operating system research, primarily distributed and parallel computation." Richard Rashid was the lead developer on the Mach project. Avie Tevanian was also one of the original developers on the Mach project.

OSX was then developed from this Mach Kernel by Steve Jobs' company NeXT. This happened during the time that Jobs was away from Apple. So Jobs' (company) developed the first iteration of OSX which was then purchased by Apple. Apple actually purchased NeXT outright, and Jobs went to serve as CEO at Apple.

<sub>Mostly from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X, and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_kernel</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The best Kernel info resource that I know of is http://google.com/search?q=Mac.OS.X.Internals+Amit.Singh